# How to use an optional parameter to filter results in a postgresql function?

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I am trying to create a function that has 3 parameters. Two of them are required dates and one is an optional string.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_sales_overviews (
  date_one DATE,
  date_two Date,
  platform_type text default null
) returns table (
  total_margin float8,
  margin_currency text
) as $$
begin
return query SELECT
  sum(margin)::float8 as total_margin,
  sales_items.margin_currency
FROM
  sales_items
  WHERE sales_items.order_date  >= date_one
  AND sales_items.order_date <= date_two
  AND sales_items.source_platform_type = platform_type
GROUP BY
  sales_items.margin_currency
ORDER BY
  total_margin DESC;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

When I run

```sql
select * from get_sales_overviews('2023-1-2', '2023-1-3', 'myPlatform');
```

I get the correct result but leaving the marketplace out like this:

```sql
select * from get_sales_overviews('2023-1-2', '2023-1-3');
```

returns nothing. I thought postgres automatically skips NULL where clauses?
If that's not the case, how do I skip the platform_type query, if it is null?

Comment: try this : `select * from get_sales_overviews('2023-1-2', '2023-1-3', null);` there is no optional input parameter in plpgsql and the function `get_sales_overviews(date, date)` does not exist.

Comment: Still returns nothing

Comment: Do not skip it but rather coalesece it to TRUE if `platform_type` is NULL. `AND coalesce(sales_items.source_platform_type = platform_type, true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still comparing the rows to `platform_type` even if it is `NULL`, and of course that fails. You will need to adjust the query:

```
  AND (platform_type IS NULL OR sales_items.source_platform_type = platform_type)
```